# Append code to function of onclick of button

Tags: javascript

I have this button `<button id='a'></button>` which I trigger its click by js `document.getElementById('a').onclick=function(){alert('Hello world');}`.
How to append code to this function inside the tag like this `<button id='a' onclick='this.onclick; alert('hello 2');'></button>`

Comment: So 'onclick' was set up to alert `Hello world`, and then you want to add an additional handler that first calls the existing handler and alerts `Hello world` but then also calls your second handler to alert `Hello 2`.  Is that right?

Comment: `onclick="alert('hello 2');"`, perhaps? It’s unclear what you’re actually going for here and why your attempt you’ve provided doesn’t meet your requirements. You should also note that attaching `on*` handlers inline in HTML has been, for quite some time, largely considered outdated for quite some time now as it’s harder to read, more inflexible, and more difficult to maintain than attaching event handlers via the `element.addEventListener()` syntax.

Comment: Yes that what I want @Wyck

Answer (score 0):

You can call `addEventListener` to add more `click` listeners in addition to the `onclick` handler originally assigned in the HTML.  Done this way, both handlers will execute when you click the button.

```js
document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('2');
});
```

```html
<button id="a" onclick="alert('1')">Test</button>
```